# woocommerce product variantions, Move dropdown below variation name

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I recently added product variations to a few of my product pages but the variation name and drop down extends past my page width. I am looking to move the drop down under the variation name so it fits.

Here is what it currently looks like:

[image: See my variation display problem]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In Woocommerce, by default the dropdowns are  just below the label name… So this should be related to your theme's CSS styling rules. Without a live link to one of your variable products, nobody can guess what the problem is and help you.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to copy **woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php** and paste it in:

**your-theme-folder/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php**

then wrap each `<td>` element with `<tr>` element

so this [image]

should be like that:
[image]